# extract the xml of a pdf extracted by an excel

Tags: excel, xml, pdf, xml-parsing

I will explain my need. I have a structured pdf file converted from an excel file.

Now I should try to extract data from the table contained in this pdf, and the best approach, short of extracting it via regex, would be to have an xml file containing the various tags.

Unfortunately, however, as I understand it, I cannot convert the file to xml without an external tool or adobe pro.

I am using, in the specific case, uipath.

Is there a possibility, even through code, to have the structured xml, since it comes from an excel file, of this pdf?

Comment: It probably would be easier to get data from excel than from pdf.  There a more than one pdf format and to extract a table from the pdf may be difficult.  Many pdf formats are binary and proprietary.

Comment: If the source can be saved as an xps document instead then it's easier to read, but still very hard. xps files are just zip-files with text documents inside.